# Android Webview inject CSS via Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

I need to inject css in website that is loaded on my webview.

And the webpage is online not local.

Here's the lastest code i tried.

When i try to run everything stay the same and i tested to css and it does what i want.

```
private void carregaCSS() {

        String extraStyles;     
        extraStyles= "javascript: myfunction(){";

        extraStyles += " document.querySelectorAll('div.live-search-container')[0].style.display = 'none';";
        extraStyles += " document.querySelectorAll('div#top-bar')[0].style.display = 'none';";
        extraStyles += " document.querySelectorAll('span#btn-mobile-toggle')[0].style.display = 'none';";
        extraStyles += " document.querySelectorAll('div#cart')[0].style.display = 'none';";
        extraStyles += " document.querySelectorAll('div.col-md-7')[0].style.display = 'none';";
        extraStyles += " }";
        Log.d("extraextraStyles",extraStyles.toString());
        mWebView.loadUrl(extraStyles);      
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manage to make it work, i just needed to call the function after creating it.

```
private void carregaCSS() {
        final String extraStyles;       
        extraStyles= "javascript: "
        + "function css(){ "
            + " document.querySelectorAll('div.live-search-container')[0].style.display = 'none';"
            + " document.querySelectorAll('div#top-bar')[0].style.display = 'none';"
            + " document.querySelectorAll('span#btn-mobile-toggle')[0].style.display = 'none';"
            + " document.querySelectorAll('div#cart')[0].style.display = 'none';"
            + " document.querySelectorAll('div.col-md-7')[0].style.display = 'none';"
            + " document.querySelectorAll('div.breadcrumb')[0].style.display = 'none';"
        + "}" 
        +"css();"

        +"";
        mWebView.loadUrl(extraStyles);
        }
}
```